# Another alternative way of writing my "Try Again" loop?

Tags: c++, loops, switch-statement

So I have a code that finds the smallest number without an array. I need to ask if the user wants to try again. So I used Switch/Case statements with goto statements. My problem is that when the first try has the smaller integer than the second one it keeps printing the first smallest integer.

I used this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int numberV;
    char a;

    label:printf("How many numbers:");
    scanf("%d",&numberV);

    if(numberV>1){
        int smallest,n;
         for(int i=0;i<numberV;i++) {
                printf("Enter a value[%d]:", i+1);
                scanf("%d", &n);
              if(smallest>n){
                    smallest = n;
              } 
         }
        printf("The smallest number is:%d",smallest);

    }
    else{
            int i=1,n;
            printf("Enter a value[%d]:", i);
            scanf("%d", &n);
            printf("The smallest number is %d",n);
        }
    label2:
    printf("\nTry again? [Y/N]: ");
    scanf(" %c", &a);

switch(a){
      case 'Y': goto label;
      case 'N': break;
      default: goto label2;
}
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any alternative way of creating my "Try again?" part or any better way?? It keeps seeing the smallest on the first sequence.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Is this intended to be C++ code, or is it just C? The languages do have significantly different tools available.

Comment: Tip: Try and consolidate functionality into functions so that they're more self-contained, more easily tested. Right now you're tripping over your own variables.

Comment: This looks almost like a line-for-line translation from code in some ancient BASIC for an 8-bit machine like an Apple II or Commodore 64...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, ignoring the problems with the structure of the code, the bug you're encountering is here:

```cpp
         int smallest,n;
         for(int i=0;i<numberV;i++) {
             printf("Enter a value[%d]:", i+1);
             scanf("%d", &n);
             if(smallest>n){
                 smallest = n;
             }
```

What value will `smallest` contain when you use it in the `if (smallest>N)` on the first iteration of the loop?

Once you've fixed that, you might want to put your code up for review on Stack Exchange's [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site. It could definitely benefit from some restructuring (but that's more or less off-topic here).